# Woocommere checkout page error?

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to find the origin of this error but i can't find it.

[image]

This error randomly shows up on the checkout page, any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you not neccesary to use postal code you can disable them by adding this function to yout functions.php

```
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) 
{
    unset( $address_fields['postcode'] );
    return $address_fields;
}
```